# ESAPI.IntrusionDetector not found in ESAPI.properties

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, esapi

I've a JSP page, where i'll accept First Name, email, phone, location and comments.

In this page firstname and comments will accept special characters.

When i click on Send button it will throw an error for below characters.

```
! * ? \ % } { = < > ~ `
```

but, if i send these below characters it will not throw any error, it will pass these characters

```
@ # $ ^ & ( ) _ + - ' " : ; / . , | ] [
```

When i pass below characters

```
! * ? \ % } { = < > ~ `
```

i'll get these errors

```
SecurityConfiguration for ESAPI.IntrusionDetector not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultIntrusionDetector
SecurityConfiguration for Logger.LogEncodingRequired not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: false
SecurityConfiguration for ESAPI.HTTPUtilities not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultHTTPUtilities
SecurityConfiguration for ESAPI.HTTPUtilities not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultHTTPUtilities
SecurityConfiguration for ESAPI.Authenticator not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: org.owasp.esapi.reference.FileBasedAuthenticator
SecurityConfiguration for ESAPI.Authenticator not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: org.owasp.esapi.reference.FileBasedAuthenticator
```

Comment: Missing information.  What validator call are you using?  The "errors" you're seeing below aren't errors, those are just standard for ESAPI when it loads.  

Please include relevant JSP code and controller code for the page.

Comment: Thank you, you are right i was missing that part i have included those characters in that property file. After adding that it is working fine.:)

Comment: Whoa... what regex did you change?  Accepting these characters:  `! * ? \ % } { = < > ~ ` in the wrong context could open your application up to a host of attacks!  What you're doing is potentially dangerous!